# Send reply to broadcast with a Socket

Tags: c#, networking, sockets, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to send a broadcast and then let the server reply to it:

```
public static void SendBroadcast()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);

        socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 16789));
        socket.Send(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Anyone out there?"));

        var ep = socket.LocalEndPoint;

        socket.Close();

        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.Bind(ep);
        socket.Receive(buffer);
        var data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("Got reply: " + data);

        socket.Close();
    }

    public static void ReceiveBroadcast()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        var iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 16789);
        socket.Bind(iep);

        var ep = iep as EndPoint;
        socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref ep);
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast: " + data + " from: " + ep.ToString());

        buffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Yeah me!");
        socket.SendTo(buffer, ep);

        socket.Close();
    }
```

The broadcast arrives fine, but the reply doesn't. No exception is thrown. Can anyone help me? Do I have to open a new connection for the reply or something?

EDIT: Changed my code a bit, and now it works! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like your `SendBroadcast()` socket is bound to a port so he's not going to receive anything. In fact your `ReceiveBroadcast()` socket is sending the reply back his own port so he will receive his own reply.

```
ReceiveBroadcast: binds to port 16789
SendBroadcast:    sends to port 16789
ReceiveBroadcast: receives datagram on port 16789
ReceiveBroadcast: sends reply to 16789
ReceiveBroadcast: **would receive own datagram if SendTo follwed by Receive**
```

You need to (a) have `SendBroadcast()` bind to a *different* port and change `ReceiveBroadcast()` send to that port (instead of his own endpoint `ep`), or (b) have both functions use the same socket object so they can *both* receive datagrams on port 16789.